# Output PHP array into unordered list

Tags: php

New to php: I have a simple array:

```
$people = array('Joe','Jane','Mike');
```

How do I output this into a list?

```
<ul>
 <li>Joe</li>
 <li>Jane</li>
 <li>Mike</li>
</ul>
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated?

Comment: This is basic PHP. Use a loop.

Comment: http://php.net/foreach

Answer (score 25):

You can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) and print the list:

```
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $people) . '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

Note this would print an empty `<li>` for an empty list - You can add a check in to make sure the array isn't empty before producing any output (which you would need for any loop so you don't print an empty `<ul></ul>`).

```
if( count( $people) > 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $people) . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a concise way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($people as $p){
 echo '<li>'.$p.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach(people as $person){
  echo "<li>". $person ."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loop to output array data as text.

There are multiple loops in PHP:

#### FOR

For will iterate $i (can be diferent variable and different change than iteration) and will end when the condition is not true anymore.

```
$people = array('Joe','Jane','Mike');
for($i=0; $i<count($people); $i++) {  //end when $i is larger than amount of people
    echo "  <li>{$people[$i]}</li>\n";
}
```

#### FOREACH

Very useful for unordered arrays - this loop will give you all values in the array as variable you want:

```
$people = array('Joe','Jane','Mike');
foreach($people as $human) {  //end when $i is larger than amount of people
    echo "  <li>$human</li>\n";
}
```

#### WHILE

Like FOR, loops while condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

echo "<ul>";

foreach(array("test", "test2", "test3") as $string)) {
    echo "<li>".$string."</li>"
}

echo "<ul>";

?>
```