# Comma separated value in unordered list php

Tags: php, arrays, list, unordered

I have Value in table like abc1, abc2, abc3... abcN, I want to retrieve this value as a unordered list,

- abc1
- abc2

I m not a expert so please explain me if possible, how i can get it in unordered list.

I want to retrieve data from database table

I have no code, But I want to do it like as i asked, If any one can help with it, I just need code for it, i have db connection..etc, I need help how i can get it this way (unordered list) from database.

Thanks,

Comment: This question is a little confusing.   Are you looking to retrieve data from a database table?  Please provide some more information.

Comment: Add some code to that question, and we might be able to help you out. "Making an unordered list out of a table" doesn't really make for a great conversation here.

Comment: I want to retrieve data from database table

Comment: So, do you have any code to show at all, or do you want us to write it all out for you? We're gladly helping with any issues you might have with your code, but we're not here to do the work for you.

Comment: I have no code, But I want to do it like as i asked, If any one can help with it, I just need code for it, i have db connection..etc, I need help how i can get it this way (unordered list) from database.

Comment: ", i have db connection." so you have code, so that's as start pleas post, we dont even know what API you use to connect ot the db

Comment: If that data is stored in the database explode that then use while loop or foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that you have to do.

1. Fetch data from database.

For that you can use, eg. [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) library.

2. Explode your data by comma.

To achieve it you need only one function, [explode()](http://php.net/explode).

```
$array = explode(', ', $commaSeparatedData);
```

Comment: "Elon Than" Ok, after this what i have to do ? I mean how i can convert in unordered list after $array = explode(', ', $commaSeparatedData); ?

Comment: `$array` variable will contain your list. That's all you have to do.

Comment: May you please write some code for it, as I said, I m not good in it, I m not understanding, how to write now next line ? I will be thankful to you.

Comment: Sorry but it's not possible. We can't write code for you. You have to do it by yourself. Just spend some time and read links from my answer.

Comment: OK, I m going to try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814393/output-php-array-into-unordered-list