# Adding Bullets to Preset Textarea Output - PHP

Tags: php, textarea, echo

I am trying to add bullets to my defined `texture` output. I simply created a `textarea` in php with some preset text. How can I preface each piece of preset text with a bullet. I want the text in my `textarea` to look like this:

- Name:
- Address:
- DOB:
- Favorite Drink:

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  echo "<textarea name=''  id='' style='width: 565px;' rows='8' cols='60'>";
    echo "Name:";
    echo "Address:";
    echo "DOB:";
    echo "Favorite Drink:";
  echo "</textarea>";
?>
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I recommend using an unordered list.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814393/output-php-array-into-unordered-list

Comment: That's an awful lot of `echo` statements. Anyway, is there something wrong with just `echo "• Name: ";`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must use a `textarea`, you can add the 'bullet' HTML entity in the string...

```
<?php
  echo "<textarea name=''  id='' style='width: 565px;' rows='8' cols='60'>";
    echo "&#8226; Name:";
    echo "&#8226; Address:";
    echo "&#8226; DOB:";
    echo "&#8226; Favorite Drink:";
  echo "</textarea>";
?>
```

Otherwise, you can go with an unordered list as @Tim Hunter suggested:

```
<?php
  echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>Name:</li>";
    echo "<li>Address:</li>";
    echo "<li>DOB:</li>";
    echo "<li>Favorite Drink:</li>";
  echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: must use a `textarea`. Addition of `&#8226;` works well. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

To write something in text area with bullets prefix, I code it with `div` instead of `textarea`, follow the below code snippets.

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
              <ul>
                  <li>List item1</li>
                  <li>List item2</li>
                  <li>List item3</li>
                  ......
                  <li>List item(n)</li>
              </ul>
         </div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to add bullet points inside a regular textarea. You could make an editable `section` or `div` with bullet points in it, but I don't think this works well with a form.

Also, putting the bullet points inside the `textarea` will allow users to delete them.

Since I **assume** you would be submitting the input in a form at some point, why not use regular inputs wrapped in `li` elements? That way, you can use the inputs in a submittable `form`, and the bullet points can't be deleted.

You can even style it to look like one big `textarea`!

```
<style>
    #form { border: solid #666 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
    #form input { border: 0; -webkit-appearance: none; background-color: unset; }
    #form input:focus { outline: none; }
</style>

<form id="form">
    <ul>
        <li>Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Name"></li>
        <li>Address: <input type="text" placeholder="Address"></li>
        <li>DOB: <input type="text" placeholder="DOB"></li>
        <li>Favorite Drink: <input type="text" placeholder="Favorite Drink"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/7tw21m3o/  <--- in action